# Regex combining English, Japanese and Chinese alphabets

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this line of code:

```
reportName = replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9 -]/g, "").replace(/[_\s]/g, '-');
```

I'm checking for alphanumeric characters and replacing spaces with dashes. I need to add Japanese and Chinese alphabets to this, but what is the correct way to add these in the aforementioned code?

I've tried multiple combinations, but after adding other alphabets, characters like "?&*" start getting through as well.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Does it have to be ONLY English/Jap/Chn? or can it be any language letters?

Comment: `\p{L}` matches any character from the Unicode category "letters". See [this](https://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html) for details. If it's OK for you to also match other languages, this could be a very handy feature.

Comment: Can you post an example of a string you want it to work with?

Comment: If you can use ES2018, this feature can help: http://exploringjs.com/es2018-es2019/ch_regexp-unicode-property-escapes.html and https://github.com/tc39/proposal-regexp-unicode-property-escapes/blob/master/README.md